# Python create a street address table

Tags: python, python-3.x

Very new to programming, very new to Python, I take different tasks online. The goal is to accomplish a lot without relying on external libraries.

One task I couldn't do today is this one:

Given a street name and a user provided number, create a table of user_provided_number columns and output the name of the street. Then, in the same table create the same output but reverse the street address. The space between the street addresses should be replaced with a "|". If the street name is too short to complete the row, render "?" for each remaining space.

Scenario Example:

Street address: Mystreet road, user provided number: 6

Expected output:

```
M y s t r e
e t | r o a
d | d a o r
| t e e r t
s y M ? ? ?
```

So far I managed to do the following:

```
strAddress = input("What's your street address?")
givenNumber = input("What's your favourite number from 1 to 10?")
reverseAddress = strAddress[::-1]
splitAddress = list(strAddress)
for row in range(0,int(len(strAddress)/givenNumber)):
    for element in range(0,givenNumber):
        print (splitAddress[element], end=' ')
    print()
```

Why is this "array"(?) printing the same elements on each row? Assuming that the user provided "4" as their number, from the code I wrote I expected an output like that:

```
M y s t
r e e t
  r o a
d
```

however the output is:

```
M y s t
M y s t
M y s t
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you should convert your `givenNumber` into `int()` since `input()` always returns string. Also you could convert your whole `strAddress` into itself and reversed version of itself to make accessing it easier. `splitAddress` wont be needed here since you can access string length and elements the same way as list in this example. In your first loop you're iterating over `len(strAddress)/givenNumber` which isn't enough since we need to print our Address two times (with reversed version) and we need to fill extending characters with `?` so we need to round it up, without using `math` library we could do this like I've shown. Lastly `splitAddress[element]` here you access element'th index of your Address which will be number `0 - 6` on every iteration so we need take into account `row` to print more elements.

```
strAddress = input("What's your street address?")
givenNumber = int(input("What's your favourite number from 1 to 10?"))

strAddress += '|' + strAddress[::-1]
strAddress = strAddress.replace(' ', '|')

lines_to_print = len(strAddress)//givenNumber + (len(strAddress)%givenNumber>0)
for row in range(lines_to_print):
    for element in range(givenNumber):
        if row*givenNumber + element < len(strAddress):
            print(strAddress[row*givenNumber + element], end=' ')
        else:
            print('? ', end='')
    print()
```

**Output for `Mystreet road` and `6`**

```
M y s t r e 
e t | r o a 
d | d a o r 
| t e e r t 
s y M ? ? ?
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that the nested loop starts back at 0 every time and ends at the same place every time. With your current code, the first loop is just declaring how many times to do the second loop, it doesn't have any input on the second loop. To fix this you could do `for element in range(givenNumber*(row-1),givenNumber*(row))`.

Answer (score 0):

You never progress through the street address.  `row` takes on values 0, 1, 2; but you never use those values to move along the address string.  Look at what you print:

```
for element in range(0,givenNumber):
    print (splitAddress[element], end=' ')
```

This prints the same four characters, regardless of the `row` value.  Instead, you need to *truly* split the address into rows and print those.  Alternately, you can compute the correct indices for each row: `givenNumber*row + element`.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to just build your string (replace characters, reverse it, ...) and then print this string character by character for each defined row. In order to calculate the number of filling characters for the last row, you could make use of the modulo operator with negative numbers.

Say your final string (`chars`) is 27 characters long and the given cell number (`givenNumber`) is 7. This would result in `-27 % 7 = 1`. So in this case one filling character would need to be added. `chars += charFill * numCharFill` will then just add the filling character x times at the end.

With an index you can then go through your string step by step and configure the output as required.

```
# strAddress = input("What's your street address?")
# givenNumber = int(input("What's your favourite number from 1 to 10?"))
strAddress = "Mystreet road"
givenNumber = 6

charFill = "?" # char to fill last row

chars = strAddress.replace(" ","|") # replace spaces in strAddress
chars += "|" + chars[::-1] # add reverse chars
numCharFill = -len(chars)%givenNumber # modulo of negative number
chars += charFill * numCharFill # add fill character x times

index = 0
for char in chars:
    if index > 0 and not index%givenNumber:
        print()
    print(chars[index], end=' ')
    index = index + 1
```

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
strAddress = input("What's your street address?\n")
givenNumber = int(input("What's your favourite number from 1 to 10?\n"))

charGroupSize = len(strAddress)/givenNumber

charGroups = [strAddress[i:i+givenNumber] for i in range(0, len(strAddress), givenNumber)]

for group in charGroups:
    for char in group:
        print (char, end=' ')
    print()
```

Output:

```
What's your street address?
Mystreet road
What's your favourite number from 1 to 10?
4
M y s t 
r e e t 
  r o a 
d
```